# Teamcity - Transform web.config and password.config upon build using MSBuild SlowCheetah 2.5.48

Tags: c#, msbuild, teamcity, slowcheetah, teamcity-10

I'm using TeamCity (`TeamCity Enterprise 10.0.4 (build 42538)`) as a build server and SlowCheetah for config transformations. My solution consist of one `ASP.NET Web API 2` project and one `Console application`.

For my console application the transformation works flawlessly for Release configuration. This is done via the `Visual Studio` runner set for `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015`.

[image]

However for publishing I use the MSBuild runner instead and here transformation does not work at all. I need to transform both a web.config file and separate password.config file. I'm using SlowCheetah 2.5.48. When publishing through Visual Studio in my development environment transformation works flawlessly as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding two system properties, added `system.PublishUrl` to have separate folder from development environment but it is not needed.

Needed parameters:

- `system.PublishProfile` - set to the value of your PublishProfile (such
  as Release)
- `system.DeployOnBuild` - set to true

When this is done TeamCity will automatically pass these parameters to your Visual Studio build step and transformation now works.

[image]

After this I could remove the MSBuild step and only use Visual Studio Runner.